# AddEventListener of function inside an AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Here is my problem: I have to add an event listener to a `DOM object` binding it to a function that is inside a controller of an `AngularJS function`.

Here is the code:

### HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <table>
      <ul id="main_ul">
      </ul>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

### JS

```
var day = document.createElement('li');
day.innerHTML = 'Click Here';
day.myDate = new Date();
document.getElementById('main_ul').appendChild(day);
day.addEventListener("click", onClickAgenda, false);
```

### AngularJS

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    function onClickAgenda() {
        $scope.selectedDate = this.myDate;
    }
});
```

I get the error that the function `onClickAgenda()` is not defined.

I know that this can be fixed by declaring the function as:

```
function onClickAgenda() {
  console.log(this.myDate);
}
```

inside my JS file. But I need it to be inside the controller. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-options for the select box and populate the option using a scope array.

[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Then you should use ng-click on element and not addEventListener https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

ng-options works for select boxes only ( i gave the wrong answer)

For your case you can use `ng-repeat` on a scope array and dynamically push items to the array from the controller.

```
<ul id="main_ul" ng-repeat="listItem in collection">
   <li ng-click="handlerFunction()">{{listItem}}</li>
</div>
```

Comment: I have considered that, but I need to add the attribute dynamically on the DOM object. How could I do that with `ng-click`?